# SLURM controller not being able to connect to workers and state is set as UNKNOWN

Tags: installation, configuration, admin, slurm

I am trying to setup a small cluster, managed with SLURM. The controller is also a compute node. The config in `/etc/slurm/slurm.conf` is:

```bash
NodeName=controller,node[01-02] RealMemory=250000 Sockets=1 CoresPerSocket=32 ThreadsPerCore=2 State=UNKNOWN
PartitionName=compute Nodes=ALL Default=YES MaxTime=INFINITE State=UP
```

When running `sinfo` I get:

```bash
PARTITION AVAIL  TIMELIMIT  NODES  STATE NODELIST
compute*     up   infinite      2   unk* node[01-02]
compute*     up   infinite      1   idle controller
```

However, when running `slurmd -C` on each node I get:

```bash
NodeName=node01 CPUs=64 Boards=1 SocketsPerBoard=1 CoresPerSocket=32 ThreadsPerCore=2 RealMemory=257655
UpTime=0-00:30:44
```

The same on the other node. I have allowed the ports `6817` and `6818` (the default slurm ports) on all machines (for TCP - which I assume is the protocol). I have also checked that the `/etc/slurm/slurm.conf` and `/etc/slurm/slurmdbd.conf` are the same, along with the munge keys (this works).

Is there anyway to debug the connection to a given machine?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to go through the log files and found out the connections were being blocked. The cluster is using Fedora and so I added each machine to the firewall trusted list using this link - [whitelist source ip addresses in centos 7](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/159873/whitelist-source-ip-addresses-in-centos-7)

These updated firewall settings did not seem to be applied straight away so I had to restart all machines and now SLURM is functioning correctly.